# react display property with number

Tags: reactjs

In reactjs I want to display a property.
Normally this isn't really hard to do it, but this time there is a number in the property. And that number depends on how many links the user has added.

This is an example of what my api returns to my react app:

```
embed_links: ["2"] 
embed_links_0_embed_link: ["https://www.url.com"] 
embed_links_1_embed_link: ["https://www.url.com"]
```

The embed_links is an array which says how many urls the user has filled in.
Then you get the urls the user has filled in, and each one has a number in it.

This is where I got stuck. I have tried to display the links with a for loop like this:

```
let embed_links = this.props.embed_links[0]
for (let i = 0; i < embed_links; i++) {
    console.log(this.props.embed_links_[i]_embed_link[0]);
}
```

But this does not work..
So my question is basically, is there a possibility that you can display properties witch custom variables/numbers in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking access to a dynamical property within your object:

`console.log(this.props["embed_links_" + i + "_embed_link"][0]);`

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks! I didn't know that this was also possible. This works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, the correct way to write this is as follows:

```
let embed_links = this.props.embed_links[0]
for (let i = 0; i < embed_links; i++) {
    console.log(this.props['embed_links_' + i + '_embed_link][0]);
}
```

In the example, `'embed_links_' + i + '_embed_link'` is the key that you use to select the correct property of object `props`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `this.props['embed_links_' + i + '_embed_link'][0]`

However i would suggest storing your embed links in an array as objects

```
embed_links_collection: [
  {  
    url:'https://www.url.com', 
    id: '1'
  }
]
```

This is a cleaner, managable solution  - you could also generate your embed_links property as this.props.embed_links_collection.length

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I know, only I cannot change the output of the api, that is a third part company...

Answer (score 0):

You can use for .. in for enumerating this.props properties